# Is there any downside in combining the ingestion of NR and NMN supplements to increase one's level of NAD+?

Tags: anti-aging, nicotinamide-riboside

From this excerpt from Robert Kane Pappas' 2014 interview with [Leonard Guarente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_P._Guarente) (MIT professor, co-founder of  the dietary supplement company Elysium Health, which sells nicotinamide riboside and pterostilbene (NRPT) pills), in which he discusses taking compounds which increase nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide (NAD) and sirtuin activity, I heard https://youtu.be/Mpf923bUDyc?t=3m10s:

> They are the 2 types of NAD precursors that are  being used right now: one is called [nicotinamide riboside (NR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_riboside) and the other is called [nicotinamide mononucleotide (NMN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_mononucleotide). Both of them are very similar to each other and they both get converted into NAD inside of cells. **Are these things (NR and NMN) used in combination? No**.

Is there any downside in combining the ingestion of nicotinamide riboside (NR) and nicotinamide mononucleotide (NMN) supplements to increase one's level of  [nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide (NAD+)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide)?

I am aware of the [metabolic pathways that synthesize and consume NAD+ in vertebrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide&oldid=830942901#Biosynthesis):

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91496/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-is-there-any-downside-in-combining).